# Steganography TriBond™

Tags: knowledge, steganography, history, real, tribond

These three have a technological
attribute — me — in common:

[image: impressed handwriting | SLATIPAC DERORRIM DESSERPMI | .txetkcalb-no-kcalbdesreveR]

•  
     What does each of these represent?

 •   
     How have these figured into actual criminology puzzles?
     
     
     
     <sup>(No need to cite specific cases.)</sup>
     

 •   
     What am I?

No wordplay is afoot and
completeness includes a note about technologically historical context.
Thus,
“they are writing -
       I am a sentence -
       judges have to figure out criminal sentences”
would be discounted on account of incompleteness and wordplay.


<sub>(No encrypted data, by the way, just one low-contrast level of writing.)</sub>

Comment: uhmmm, i only se two boxes unless the middle with no side border is the 2nd one lol

Comment: Why do you use so few markdown?

Comment: Nah, the markdown isn't  part of the puzzle, no matter how much it constitutes a kind of steganography itself. Just wish I could adjust some CSS settings for this site.

Comment: @humn I finished the edit and added in your historical note

Comment: Thanks once again, @Areeb, for both starting the solution and for completing it! Another 12 hours before the bounty comes through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The image in Areeb's answer is helpful but a bit difficult to read. Enhancing the image by balancing the levels produces:

[image: enhanced image]

The first item is clearly:

> An imprint left behind on a piece of paper beneath the paper being written on. It can be read more easily by rubbing a pencil across it, and features in pretty much every murder mystery ever written (and I'm sure a few real cases too).

The second item:

> Is the paper left behind when you peel off a label from an embossing machine. The unique printing method employed by embossing machines leaves a mirrored imprint. The process is explained in more detail [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embossing_tape)

And the third item appears to be:

> The imprint left on a typewriter ribbon (the ink-covered ribbon pressed against the paper when typing the letters). If the ribbon is fresh, or recently wound, it would be possible to see some of what was written by looking at where the ink is slightly depleted.

So overall:

> They're all imprints left behind after writing something, which can be used to determine the content of an otherwise lost or hidden message, or tie a particular document to the location it was written ("why this Will is a fake; it was written on YOUR typewriter *points to the murderer*")

Historical Note:

> All of these "office tools" were eventually computerized. [Humn said this in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32372406#32372406)

Comment: For the middle imprint: Why would it be backwards? This is where trivia comes to play, the technology being very familiar 1960+ through 1990+ in the parts of Europe and USA where I was, but it seems possible to figure out.

Comment: @humn ok, I'm trying to think of a technology which presses in reverse and is limited to block capitals, but nothing's coming to mind. Maybe somebody else will be able to figure that one out; I wasn't around for the 1960s–80s!

Comment: @humn is there a reason only the first one is completely boxed?

Comment: Quite so, @Areeb, mainly because there is a reason why the other two are not boxed

Comment: Whaddayaknow, supplies of/for the middle item continue to be stocked
on actual shelves in stores around the world.
The level-balanced picture here happens to look extremely realistic
and is almost life-size.
Well call me Rip Van Winkle and wake me up again in another 25 years.

Comment: @humn No I didn't look through your other questions, which might've been smart, I was searching up machines used in the 60s-80s

Comment: Good sleuthing, @Areeb, though you'll see that the tape looks different after all. (Nothing in my other posts relates to this beyond the time frame.)  I hope your edit becomes official in any case. Sometimes short edits don't.

Comment: Thanks @humn , it probably will. Is the handwriting boxed because it isn't mechanical?

Comment: Ah so that's what it is. I'd never heard of a telex machine before! Also on the boxing stuff: I don't know how to do spoilers in a comment, so if you want to figure out the "boxes" yourself stop reading now, but the yellow outline is actually the background table. The bottom 2 are simply continuous ribbons which continue past the edges, while the first item is a small piece of paper on the table.

Comment: @Dave I figured it was something like that

Comment: The observation about boxing would be good to see in the answer at some point, a deliberate clue

Comment: @humn I'm guessing the telex machine was not the right answer

Comment: Alas, @Areeb, a Telex leaves behind punched-out paper dots, although the technology in question does have an option for braille. I'll accept any good reason for an imprint to be mirrored, even if it's not the intended reason. I've looked through more than a hundred current online pictures of the technology in mind but none of them show the imprint, which is nonetheless completely familiar to all users.

Comment: @Dave if you're still around, me and humn worked out the second part of the puzzle in chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32372372#32372372

Answer (score 3):

**Not an answer**

The three boxes say:

1. "Impressed Handwriting"
   -Written in cursive
2. "Impressed Mirrored Capitals"
   -It's mirrored
3. "Reversedblack-on-blacktext.Reversedblack-on"
   -Message is close to description
   -the background is bluish 
   -the writing is self is rgb(10,10,0) 
   -background is rgb(0,0,20) 
   -the color codes don't hold any data

Image: Courtesy of Will(updated by humn)
[image: crude screenshot]

The actual image itself is supposed to look like a photograph

Comment: [Crude screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/zuB7v.png)

Comment: @humn does that mean there is one more or that I already have it?

Comment: @Will what aspects are different?

Comment: Oddly, the third piece of text does not _quite_ describe itself (though it's close).

Comment: Ran out of space to describe that characteristic, @Will, that's all, but the characteristic itself is indeed a clue

Comment: @Areeb It's not black-on-black. It's black-on-very-dark-but-visibly-blue.

Comment: Oops, make that two characteristics missing from the self-description. Good eye, @will, it's also a clue. By the way, even the writing isn't exactly black but the hues are not numerical, just meant to be subliminal cues to help evoke memories.

Comment: @humn does it possibly have anything to do with how the message was written? It looks like it was printed

Comment: @Areeb The "black" that's not blue is actually `rgb(10,10,0)`.

Comment: @Will noted, have a color for the background?

Comment: @Areeb Sure, `rgb(0,0,20)`.

Comment: Indeed, Areeb, these images try to represent the methods used for producing such messages in reality.

Comment: @humn darn, I'm having a hard time explaining the mirroring part cohenrently

Comment: @humn thanks! I now better understand how it works